# Why is my persistence file not increasing ?

Tags: live-usb, files, persistence

I have an NTFS formatted drive with Ubuntu 14.04 on it and I'm trying to increase my persistence file, but no matter what, it won't increase.  I've tried this with previous versions of Ubuntu as well, but I'd get errors rather than a failed increase.  I've followed [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/) tutorial.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong from the images in these two links?(The format of the two images are unsupported for posting here):

http://i4.minus.com/jlppdBwbWrEeg.png

http://i2.minus.com/jEWKwv198X5ZE.png

Comment: What is the total size of your (flash?) drive? Increase the (size?) of your persistence file(system?)?

Comment: 32GB SanDisk Glide

Answer (score 0):

You can not increase the size of a persistence file beyond 4GB on a FAT32 file system, (I've never seen a persistent install work on a NTFS file system).

In order to use a persistent partition you may need to delete the persistent casper-rw file, the pendrivelinux tutorial assumes you created the pendrive using "extra space" and a casper-rw file was created, if not you need to add the word persistent in either text.cfg, txt.cfg or syslinux.cfg as follows:

```
append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash noprompt
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've followed [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/) tutorial.

This is about a persistence partition, e.g. a partition with an EXT filesystem labled `casper-rw`. So what are you actually using, a file or a partition?

If you are using a file, how are you trying to increase the file size? To my knowledge these files are created by allocating a file in the filesystem with zeros, mounting it as a loopback device and formatting it with a filesystem. I don't know of a way to increase/extend such files without destroying the filesystem. The only solution I can think of is creating a new file with the desired size, mounting it, formatting it and copying the contents over.